# golang unexpected directory layout

Tags: go, goland

So I downloaded minio from github.com/minio/minio

I want to run it from the source,

I create my directory like:

```
~/Downloads/minio-RELEASE.2017-06-13T19-01-01Z
|
 src
   |
    all minio directories, including vendor, like the image below
```

[image]

I also use `godep` resolve other dependencies under GOPATH.

Now I run it from Gogland(go IDE)

It shows:

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec
GOPATH=/Users/xl/Downloads/minio-RELEASE.2017-06-13T19-01-01Z:/Users/xl/go
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/bin/go build -i -o /private/var/folders/8v/6dg7d6mx2850sv1gp8ts9thm0000gn/T/go_run_main_gogo /Users/xl/Downloads/minio-RELEASE.2017-06-13T19-01-01Z/src/main.go
unexpected directory layout:
    import path: github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage
    root: /Users/xl/Downloads/minio-RELEASE.2017-06-13T19-01-01Z/src
    dir: /Users/xl/Downloads/minio-RELEASE.2017-06-13T19-01-01Z/src/vendor/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage
    expand root: /Users/xl/Downloads/minio-RELEASE.2017-06-13T19-01-01Z/src
    expand dir: /Users/xl/Downloads/minio-RELEASE.2017-06-13T19-01-01Z/src/vendor/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage
    separator: /
```

Now I am confused that, what's the problem? The files are all there and the directories are just like what's it's printing. How do I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [GitHub code layout](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GithubCodeLayout)

> `$GOPATH` is the root of the project - each of your Github repos will be checked out several folders below `$GOPATH`.
>   Your `$GOPATH` variable will point to the root of your Go workspace, as described in [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html).

In your case, below your `GOPATH` folder, you should have

```
src/github.com/minio/minio
```

Anf only *then* "all minio directories, including vendor"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am new to go and still unclear how to fix it.. you said I should have `src/github.com/minio/minio`, but minio I have is the source code directly, not downloaded bo `go get`

Comment: @Wingzero create `GOPATH/src/github.com/minio`, then clone your repo inside that folder: that will give you `GOPATH/src/github.com/minio/minio`, and `go build` will work then. Or, simply try a `go get github.com/minio/minio`: that should do the same (clone + build)

Comment: Amazing, it's working. Thanks a lot! One pity is Gogland still fails to debug break at my breakpoint. Anyway

Comment: If you tell me where to set the breakpoints I'll follow up with an issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go and hopefully fix it.

Answer (score 26):

On Golang 1.13 it suddenly happened to me on all my code after upgrading from 1.11 to 1.13.

It seems golang 1.13 does not like anymore imports like "./something".

I had to develop any import like "myapp/something"

Comment: Addendum: Now the best way is to use modules. create a module from your code with go mod init, then insert the reference to your directories as a 'replace' directive. See https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules for more info

Answer (score 6):

This can happen if you have duplicate repos under goroot AND gopath. Delete the goroot one.

Answer (score 3):

Also with go1.13 (with the move to go mod), I found if I moved my project out from under my $GOPATH, I could use the **import "./mypackage"** statement. The same project under $GOPATH wouldn't build with the errors given by the OP above. I'm not ready to give up my $GOPATH environment variable just yet but I do like to keep small packages local to their project when possible, without committing to a go.mod file when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If your project folders are under $GOPATH directory, Then you should import your packages without using "./package".

You can import packages with "./package" name only if your project files are outside the $GOPATH

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after I realised that I can't import correctly local packages, due to my project location. 
My project was not in the GOPATH location, so I moved my project there. Before moving

I imported packages via ./package name and after I moved my project in the GOPATH, I imported packages correctly via projectname/packagename.

So what I've done was to import packages the correct way "projectname/packagename", so I corrected my import "./packagename" to ""projectname/packagename.
Hopefully it's not too confusing. It seems that this error can appear from different situations.